# Individual field form error message not displaying in Symfony 2.1

Tags: symfony-2.1

I have a simple form in Symfony 2.1 and when I submit it, I expect to see some error messages displayed on my form page because I denoted some fields as required.

However, the `{{ form_errors(form.company_name) }}` approach to show the error message of that particular field doesn't work for me. It never displays the message. However, if I use `{{form_errors(form)}}`, all the error messages are displayed in one place. I need the individual `{{form_errors(form.company_name)}}` way of doing it to work. Did anybody experience this? What could be wrong? Here is my twig code:

```
<form method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} novalidate>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td class="field-cell">{{ form_label(form.promo_referral) }}:&nbsp;</td>
    <td>{{ form_errors(form.promo_referral) }}{{ form_widget(form.promo_referral) }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="field-cell">{{ form_label(form.company_name) }}:&nbsp;</td>
    <td>{{ form_errors(form.company_name) }}{{ form_widget(form.company_name) }}</td>
  </tr>
  ...
```

Here is my relevant Controller code:

```
$registration = new ServiceVendorRegistration();
$form = $this->createForm(new ServiceRegisterForm(), $registration);

if ($request->isMethod("POST")) 
{
    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
              // do something else
    }
}

return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:register_service_vendor.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
```

Validation.yml makes the field required as follows:

```
properties:
        companyName:
            - NotBlank:
                message: You have to fill this
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the solution. Symfony doesn't like it when I name my form fields using underscore to separate words, like first_name. It relies on camelCase naming convention. When I renamed my form fields correspondingly, it started working right.

Comment: Three years later, Thank you ! This short answer saved me after two days of searching.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ServiceRegisterForm to validate if your form fields are as 'required' or in the Entity definition

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it. I tried to add the form property "required" => true, but it didn't help.

Comment: I should also add that I noticed that the a field of the 'password' type renders the error message only using {{ form_errors(form.password.first) }}, but doesn't render it in global errors via {{ form_errors(form) }}. This behavior is opposite to all other fields. So weird. What could it be about? This is how the password field is defined in the form: $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array("type" => "password", "invalid_message" => "The password fields must match", "first_options" => array("label" => "Password"), "second_options" => array("label" => "Retype Password")));